# text view is not showing up in relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a screen with relative layouts which contains images and text views.I am trying to add one text view but it is not showing up..I can't find out the reason.This is my whole xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/orangestrip"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:text="Choose your flag, Pay in your Home currency"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:background="@drawable/orangestrip"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:text="اختيار العلم الخاص بك، ودفع بالعملة المحلية الخاصة بك"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/stripblue"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_width="450dp"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
            android:background="@drawable/imageborder" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                android:layout_width="450dp"
                android:layout_height="500dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/imageborder" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                    android:layout_width="400dp"
                    android:layout_height="320dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton1"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
                    android:text="curr"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textSize="35sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="rate"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="450dp"
                android:layout_height="500dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                android:background="@drawable/imageborder" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                    android:layout_width="400dp"
                    android:layout_height="320dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/uae" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageButton2"
                    android:layout_marginRight="123dp"
                    android:text="curr"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textSize="35sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/mashreqlogosmall" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the relative layout where I am trying to add the text view but its not showing up...textview with id textview5 is not showing up.

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                android:layout_width="450dp"
                android:layout_height="500dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/imageborder" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                    android:layout_width="400dp"
                    android:layout_height="320dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton1"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
                    android:text="curr"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textSize="35sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="rate"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            </RelativeLayout>
```

please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="450dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
        android:text="curr"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="rate"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</RelativeLayout>
```